# Boot ubuntu from UNetBootin

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I installed ubuntu from UNetbootin, then I restarted and booted unetbootin instead of windows 10. And I opened "Install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS" from the desktop and I installed ubuntu.

The problem is that it still boots up in the "test" mode, and everything I do is erased when I restart. What can I do? And if I try to open that install again, it shows me that the partition I chose before, contains ubuntu 16.04.1.

How can I boot from that?

Comment: Remove the USB drive from your computer. Most likely, it is before the HDD in the boot order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the usb from the machine. So close it down, pull out the usb, then restart, the grub menu should come up with option to boot into ub or dozer.

If that is not the case, you could have damaged grub during a restart. You will have to reinstall ubuntu from the usb. When unetbootin finishes and you get a message asking 'exit now' or 'continue testing', chose the latter, then close it down, then pull out the usb.

Comment: I used the hard disk option. But the problem was that it didn't create the grub config correctly or something like that.

Comment: You might need to research further on this site re. dual-booting. Ubuntu might be trying to install itself in EFI mode. Basically, when you go to install Ubuntu, don't select 'install ubuntu alongside windows' but rather select 'do something else'. You may have to research your options for this...